# How to create a helper for build grids in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

i'm using `rails4/ruby2` and `haml`, trying to build a grid layout using helper
So i have this grid structure in `haml`:

```
#container
  .column
    #title
    .thumb
      = link_to '', title: '' do
        = image_tag '', alt: '', size: '196x196'
        %span.caption
          %p.title

    .thumb
      = link_to '', title: '' do
        = image_tag '', alt: '', size: '196x196'
        %span.caption
          %p.title

  .column
    #title
    .thumb
      = link_to '', title: '' do
        = image_tag '', alt: '', size: '196x196'
        %span.caption
          %p.title

    .thumb
      = link_to '', title: '' do
        = image_tag '', alt: '', size: '196x196'
        %span.caption
          %p.title
```

Someone can help me to make a helper for build this grid structure? i want to do this for don't be so `DRY` repeating many times the elements

Comment: It is invalid to have multiple elements with the same id (i.e. `#title`).

Answer (score 1):

Use `each_slice`! Assuming you have an array of images:

```
- images.each_slice(2) do |image_column|
  .column
    #title
    - image_column.each do |image|
      .thumb
        = link_to '', title: '' do
          = image_tag image.path, alt: '', size: '196x196'
          %span.caption
            %p.title
```

Comment: i dont have an array of images, you can show how this way works?

Comment: and appears .thumb don't works on .rb file, need to be used other way